# Time-Based Workflow Actions not getting executed

Tags: salesforce, workflow, sfdc

I am facing this weird issue where my time-based workflow actions are seen to be scheduled in the monitor window but are not executed within the salesforce-specified 2-hour window (in case of those scheduled in the past). In fact, some of them were created a couple of days back and were to be executed today (28-7-2020 12:00 AM) but never did. Is anyone aware of this or what could I possibly be missing here?

[Check Here for my Time based Workflow monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71qly.png)

Answer (score 0):

How many actions you have queued up that were supposed to happen in the past? SF will let you queue millions of workflow actions but execution is capped at 1000/hour.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_limits.htm&type=5 and https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5

> Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can
> execute per hour. If an organization exceeds the limits for its
> Edition, Salesforce defers the execution of the additional time
> triggers to the next hour. For example, if an Unlimited Edition
> organization has 1,200 time triggers scheduled to execute between 4:00
> PM and 5:00 PM, Salesforce processes 1,000 time triggers between 4:00
> PM and 5:00 PM and the remaining 200 time triggers between 5:00 PM and
> 6:00 PM.

You could check by running queries / reports if any Opportunities were modified today (or whatever your workflow does)

If this functionality is time-critical and you expect to have activity spikes like that in future - consider rewriting to scheduled batch job.

Comment: I happen to have just 30 odd actions that were to be executed in the past. The problem here is ever-concerning now because I see the number of scheduled action items are increasing, but not one of them is getting executed.

Comment: Interesting. If the user that scheduled them is still active, if attaching debug log doesn't show anything (maybe it fails on some validation rule? although I'd expect it to clear from the queue either way)... maybe you need to raise ticket with support. There are no "general" problems? License to some managed package expiring? Running out of storage space? Newly created/changed val. rules? Triggers?